# How to configure kendo column chaart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

How to create a COLUMN Chart using KENDO DATAVIZ

```
X - Axis = Week Number (1 through 52)

Y- Axis = money ($)

LEGEND = YEAR (2012/2013)
```

how to display the x-axis with week numbers

Comment: How have you configured it so far to try and achieve this?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ulituh/1/edit I Have tried with kendo given example but I have doubt how to configure weeks

Comment: That's just a copy of the sample with the data coded right into the chart creation. You need to ask yourself where you are going to get the data from and look at the the other samples of how to configure a chart with a remote data source.

Comment: Yes,I have a json data {
  "year": "2010",
  "week": "2",
  "money ": 7596.00
  
 }

Comment: Expand out your question with more information including your configuration and json data

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ixocov/1/edit here is what I did with sample data.My question Is for a year we have 53 weeks If I need to display weeks in x axis means Do I need to configure all of them in category axis.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32453/discussion-between-boniestlawyer-and-kvs)